# Passing data between two different Navigation Graphs

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-room

I have two different Navigation Graphs in my app.
The first one has 3 fragments: fragment with the list of created projects, fragment where i create new projects and the support fragment which has the second navigation graph.
The second navigation graph has bottom navigation and the other fragments which contain information about the created project. It activates, when user chooses one of the items in the list of created projects.
To store information about projects i use room database.

I don't really understand how I can pass the data about selected item to the second navigation graph.

I wanted to pass the selected item with the navigation graph arguments, but as the fragment in which i want to pass this data is in the other navigation graph I don't think I can use it.
I tried to make a query in my database to find the project by id, but i don't really know how to implement it in my code.

This is my dao:

```
@Dao
interface ProjectsDao {
    @Insert
    suspend fun addProjects(projects: Projects)
    @Delete
    suspend fun deleteProject(projects: Projects)

    @Query("DELETE FROM projects")
    suspend fun deleteAllProjects()

    @Query("SELECT * FROM projects WHERE projects.id = :id")
    fun findProjectById(id: Int): LiveData<Projects>

    @Update
    suspend fun updateProject(projects: Projects)
    @Query("SELECT * FROM projects")

    fun readAllProjects(): LiveData<List<Projects>>
}
```

This is my View Model (Edited):

```
class DataViewModel(application:Application): AndroidViewModel(application) {
     val readAllProjects: LiveData<List<Projects>>
     val currentProject: MutableLiveData<Projects> = MutableLiveData()

    private val repository: ProjectsRepository

    init{
        val projectsDao = ProjectsDatabase.getDatabase(application).projectsDao()
        repository = ProjectsRepository(projectsDao)
        readAllProjects = repository.readAllProjects
    }

    ....

    fun findProjectById(id: Int):LiveData<Projects>{
        return repository.findProjectById(id)
    }
    fun setCurrentItem(projects: Projects) {
        currentProject.value = projects
        //currentProject.postValue(projects)
    }
}
```

This my attempt to pass the id of selected item from `MainFragment` through adapter to the next fragment in the navigation graph `SupportFragment`. But `SupportFragment` only has the FragmentContainerView and bottom navigation. So the item data should actually be passed to the `ProjectDetailsFragment`.

```
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = projectsList[position]
        holder.binding.projectNameTxt.text = currentItem.pr_name

        setListeners(currentItem, holder)
        //holder.binding.rawLayout.setOnClickListener {
        //    val action = MainFragmentDirections.actionMainFragmentToSupportFragment(currentItem)
        //    holder.itemView.findNavController().navigate(action)
        //}
        //holder.binding.deleteProjectID.setOnClickListener{
        //    listener.deleteProject(currentItem)
        //}

    }

    private fun setListeners(currentItem: Projects, holder: MainAdapter.MyViewHolder) {
        holder.binding.rawLayout.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(holder.itemView.context, SupportFragment::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("id", currentItem.id)
            holder.itemView.context.startActivity(intent)
            //val action = MainFragmentDirections.actionMainFragmentToSupportFragment(intent)
            //holder.itemView.findNavController().navigate(action)
        }
        holder.binding.deleteProjectID.setOnClickListener{
            listener.deleteProject(currentItem)
        }
    }
```

Edit: Here is my `SupportFragment` code

```
class SupportFragment : Fragment() {
    private val arg by navArgs<SupportFragmentArgs>()
    private var _binding: FragmentSupportBinding? = null
    lateinit var viewModel : DataViewModel
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding =  FragmentSupportBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(DataViewModel::class.java)

        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val navHostFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.support) as NavHostFragment
        val navController = navHostFragment.findNavController()
        binding.bottomNav.setupWithNavController(navController)
        
        //Setting the current item value
        viewModel.setCurrentItem(arg.currentProject)

}
```

`ProjectDetailsFragment` code

```
class ProjectDetailsFragment : Fragment() {
    lateinit var viewModel: DataViewModel
    private var _binding: FragmentProjectDetailsBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        _binding = FragmentProjectDetailsBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(DataViewModel::class.java)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val setDataObserver = Observer<Projects>{project->
            binding.projectName.text = project.pr_name
        }
        //Observing currentProject
        viewModel.currentProject.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, setDataObserver)

}
```

Comment: Couldn't you create a ViewModel that holds a `currentItem` `LiveData` or `Flow`, have the bottom view set a value on that, and your other fragment(s) observe that and update when they see a new value? So long as they're all using the parent Activity's VM store (e.g. using `by activityViewModels()` like you're doing) they'll all be looking at the same data. If the Fragments aren't all visible, when you navigate to one it can hook into the VM during setup and immediately display the current item

Comment: @cactustictacs So I created the `LiveData` `currentItem` in my VIewModel, but I don't know how to set a value on that. In my `SupportFragment` I'm trying to set the argument value (which I pass through navigation graph) to it, but it has `Project` type and I need `LiveData<Project>` type

Comment: You'd just set it the usual way - write a `setCurrentItem(project: Project)` function on your VM, which does `currentItem.value = project`. Because everything's referencing the same VM object, your `SupportFragment` is setting a new value on the `LiveData` that the other fragments are observing. If you're not familiar with `LiveData`, it needs to be a `MutableLiveData` internally (which allows you to set a value) but usually exposed publicly as just `LiveData`. (You could use `StateFlow` instead if you're not already using `LiveData` and you want to just use the `Flow` libraries instead.)

Comment: @cactustictacs I created the function in my view model as you wrote and changed `currentProject` to `MutableLiveData` type, but when I am trying to observe this data in the fragment it has the null value. I am sure that SafeArgs argument is not null. I edited my post with the changes I made. Sorry, if I bothering you with this but I don't really know how to do it.

Comment: If you're not familiar with ViewModels and LiveData, you need to read up on that - it's the recommended way to share data between Fragments within a single Activity, which is what you're trying to do here. It's not using SafeArgs - you're just fetching the same ViewModel instance in each Fragment, so they're all looking at the same thing. *You're not actually doing that in your code* - by passing `this` to `ViewModelProvider` each Fragment is fetching *its own private version of the VM*, so that state isn't shared. Use `requireActivity()`, or just use `by activityViewModels()` like you were

Comment: @cactustictacs Thank you a lot, everything works fine now! I'm going to read about ViewModels more.

Answer (score 0):

first you have to modify the setListeners function to navigate to the projectsDetailsFragment

```
private fun setListeners(currentItem: Projects, holder: MainAdapter.MyViewHolder) {
    val action = MainFragmentDirections.actionMainFragmentToProjectDetailsFragment(currentItem.id)
    holder.itemView.findNavController().navigate(action)
}
```

next in second navigation graph make sure you have defined a destination for the ProjectDetailsFragment and setup the appropriate arguments for the destination

then in ProjectsDetailsFragment get the passed Id from the arguments and use it in database query:

```
class ProjectDetailsFragment : Fragment() {
    private val viewModel: DataViewModel by activityViewModels()

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val projectId = arguments?.getInt("projectId") ?: 0
        viewModel.findProjectById(projectId).observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { project ->
            // Handle the retrieved project data
        }
    }
}
```

and finally make sure you update the findProjectById in your viewModel to return the LiveData object:

```
fun findProjectById(id: Int): LiveData<Projects> {
    return repository.findProjectById(id)
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that first navigation graph includes: `MainFragment`, `AddProjectFragment` and `SupportFragment` which acts as the host of the second navigation graph. So I can't pass data directly from `MainFragment` to `ProjectDetailsFragment` as it is located in the second navigation graph. So, now the problem is how to pass the data through host fragment `SupportFragment` to `ProjectDetailsFragment`.